# requirejs and async function and use the result in a different module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm having issues rebuilding my app with requirejs.

Previous code:

```
function getData(){
    chrome.storage.local.get('settings',function(object){
        var stored_data = object;
        settings = stored_data['settings'];
        //do something with settings object
        createFromSettings(settings);
    }); 
}
getData();
```

With Requirejs (2 modules):

config.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../src/js/modules',
    paths: {     
        settings: 'getSettings',
        create_elements: 'createElements'
    }
```

getSettings.js

```
    define(function(){
        function localSettings(callback){
            chrome.storage.local.get('settings',function(object){//async
                var stored_data = object;
                settings = stored_data['settings'];
                callback(settings)
            })
        }
        return{
            getSettings:localSettings(function(data){
                console.log(data)
                //data is ok here
            })

        }
    })
```

and in createElements.js

```
define(['settings'],function(settings){
    console.log(settings.getSettings)
    //returns undefined
})
```

But it doesn't work because I cannot use return in async. I cannot understand how to use the result (settings) in createElements.js module.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `getSettings` property doesn't appear to be a function?

Comment: @Bergi yes, it should be settings.getSettings, but I don't understand why it returns undefined.

Comment: Because it doesn't `return` anything anywhere (and [cannot do that anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572))?